# How to restrict country names in the `country_select` plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), which automatically uses [country_select](https://github.com/rails/country_select) plugin when using a field named country, like this:

```
<%= f.input :country %>
```

But I want to be able to restrict the countries displayed.

I saw [country_select code defines this](https://github.com/rails/country_select/blob/master/lib/country_select.rb#L65):

```
COUNTRIES = ["Afghanistan"
  ...
"Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"] unless const_defined?("COUNTRIES")
```

So, I though I could override COUNTRIES like below:

```
<% COUNTRIES = ["Canada","USA"] %>
<p><%= f.input :country %></p>
```

But I get an error:

```
compile error
/home/jack/src/beta/app/views/contacts/_address_fields.html.erb:6: dynamic constant assignment
');  COUNTRIES = ["Canada","USA"] 
      ^
```

How to overwrite the COUNTRIES constant? Or is there a more elegant way of doing this?

**Ps.** I am using Ruby 1.8.7p330 with Rails 3.0.3

Comment: I guess this is loaded at the beginning of the Rails app. Did you try to set COUNTRIES in an initializer?

Comment: Just fyi, I generally use https://github.com/jim/carmen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `COUNTRIES` constant is already defined by the plugin by the time your view is executed. Define your `COUNTRIES` in an intializer. (See: `config/initializers`)

Edit: 
Put this in an initializer, like `config/initializers/countries.rb`:

```
ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
```

Comment: I did as suggested, but the entire list is still being shown!

Comment: See my edit, and pay attention to apneadiving's reminder to restart your server.

Comment: The problem was that I was not setting the constant using the namespace. Thanks!

Comment: Putting the constant in the initializer works, but I get a warning during server startup: `warning: already initialized constant COUNTRIES`